# OllyDbg 2: Providing label arguments?

Tags: ollydbg

I recently switched from OllyDbg 1 to 2, and I'm really missing a feature the plugin "LabelArgs" provided to me in OllyDbg 1.

Labels were extended in a way it was possible to name the first instruction of an obvious functions like "WriteToLog(int portOrOther, string title, string category, string text, int severity)". In the disassembly, calls to the functions then appeared visually like calls to known WinAPI methods, for example:
[image]

In OllyDbg 2 it looks like:
[image]

Sadly strings are not directly seen anymore, but it helped me much more seeing when pushes are about to be method parameters.

Is there an OllyDbg 2 compatible plugin providing me this feature?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the original LabelArgs plugin was open source, I ported it to OllyDbg 2. It should have the same functionality as the original LabelArgs plugin, feel free to improve on it.

Link to the repository:
https://bitbucket.org/mrexodia/labelargs

Binaries:
https://bitbucket.org/mrexodia/labelargs/downloads

Comment: Looks awesome, gonna test it soon when I come back to Olly debugging :)